# can't get a ff extension to work in v3.0.5

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

Does anyone know what might have changed since v3.0.5 that would enable extensions to work?  Or, maybe I'm missing a setting somewhere?  I wrote this add-on that works fine with newer versions, but I can't get it to launch in older ones.  Specifically, I can't even get this part to work (this is in my browser overlay.xul):

```
<html:script>
<![CDATA[

    var Cc = Components.classes;
    var Ci = Components.interfaces;
    var obSvc = Cc["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIObserverService);

    gBrowser.consoleService = Cc["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"].getService(Ci.nsIConsoleService);
    gBrowser.log = function(msg){
        this.consoleService.logStringMessage(msg);
    }

    gBrowser.newObj= new MyAddOn();
    gBrowser.log("initializing...");
    function regListener()
    {
        obSvc.addObserver(gBrowser.newObj, "http-on-modify-request", false);
    }
    function unregListener()
    {
        obSvc.removeObserver(gBrowser.newObj, "http-on-modify-request");
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", regListener, false);
    window.addEventListener("unload", unregListener, false);

]]>
```

This *should* attach listeners to the new obj (defined by a linked .js)  However, I'm not even getting the "initializing..." message in the console.  Any ideas?

Comment: Any output in the error console? ctrl-shift-J

Comment: If I remember correctly in about:config you have to set property: javascript.options.showInConsole to true to be able to see errors from the console, I might be wrong. Anyway, if it doesn't help do the following: put alert('some message'); after every line (obviously change the message for each occurence) and the last message you get when you run the browser is where your error is (following line in your code). I know it's not so sophisticated but for a small code like this it's the fastest debugging technique

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use <html:script>, use <script> (assuming you have xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" on your root <overlay> element).
2. Don't register an application-global listener (http-on-modify-request) from a window overlay. Doing so will make your code run one time in each window the user may have open. Use an XPCOM component instead - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_HTTP_request_headers
3. Don't pollute common objects (like gBrowser or the global object (with `var Cc`)) with your own properties. If everyone did that, no two extensions would work together. Put all your code properties on your own object with a unique name.

   - accessing `gBrowser` before the load event is probably what's causing your specific problem.
4. [Set up your environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment) and check the Error Console to debug problems.
5. Don't waste time trying to support Firefox 3. It's not supported by Mozilla itself for over a year and shouldn't be used to access the web.

Comment: Ok, so I took your advice and completely rewrote this.  I created a self-registering xpcom-based component, tested and working.  However, when I drop it into the target system, I get no response (I suspect it swallows errors, which is fine).  The complication is I'm not developing on the target machine, so I can't recreate the issue. I'm also not clear why not support FF3 - FF4 is still in beta.

Comment: @end-user: There are Firefox 3.0.x, 3.5.x, and 3.6.x series, which have major differences. I got confused by your subject (3.0.5) and assumed you were talking about 3.0.x, which is not supported. Firefox 3.5 was scheduled to EOL in August'10 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox_3.5#End_of_life ), and 3.6.x is fully supported and is the current release.

Comment: @end-user: and your new problem totally deserves a separate question instead of a comment discussion (with as much information as you can provide).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `gBrowser.log` is not defined, or at least is not a function, as the error console will probably tell you. I've never heard of it either. Maybe it was added in Fx 3.5?

Comment: No, you just missed it: I defined gBrowser.log as a convenience for this.consoleService.logStringMessage(msg)

Comment: Indeed I did. Personally, I wouldn't have attached that to the gBrowser, I would have attached it to the 'myExtension' object (hopefully you have one...) but that's a separate issue. I'll look again when I get a chance...

Comment: I see you do have one, but it's on `gBrowser`. Why not just put it on `window`

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot.  But I'm not sure why the extension is getting applied.  (It *is* loading - it's in the add-ons list)